# I don't get the point of making forms and header tags with PHP in Zend

Tags: html, zend-framework, zend-form

Whats is the point of going thru the trouble of programatically create a form with Zend_Form when I can just type in the markup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a lot of reasons.

- Easier maintenance - you can change configuration values without messing with the markup
- easier configuration - can even be loaded from a configuration file
- the possibility to re-use the same form definition with slightly altered settings
- easier internationalization
- built-in validation
- Increased independence from markup languages
- the possibility of outputting a form in different markup languages (HTML 4, XML, HTML 5) if necessary

I'm sure somebody more experienced with Zend_Form than me can list even more.